# Does it matter who executes a Burst skill?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-4

Anyone can use the Burst command if the Burst Gauge is high enough. But do the effects of the Burst change dependent on the user's stats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effects of almost every burst skill is affected by stats. The healing ones heal based on the character's max HP, and the physical damage ones depend on the attack stats of the user. You can even use them with charge for some very heavy damage. The magic ones deal significantly more damage is the caster has higher TEC. You can always test these out yourself though, you might surprised at how much a medic can dish out with physical skills from the front line.